# How to write a point object to a text file

Tags: java, io, fileoutputstream, filewriter, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to write a list that contains a list of points in to a text file.I've managed to write the method to save a a point to text file. However, I'm getting some extra characters in the output

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

    for(int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++){
        String s = parseString( pointList.get(i));

        out.writeObject(s);
    }

    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
} catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
}

private static String parseString(Point P){
    String point = String.valueOf(P.getX()) + "," + String.valueOf(P.getY()) ;
    System.out.println("String: " +point);
    return point;
}
```

This is the point list

```
List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList();
pointList.add(new Point(100,200));
pointList.add(new Point(300,500));
pointList.add(new Point(400,200));
pointList.add(new Point(100,500));
pointList.add(new Point(400,200![enter image description here][1]));
```

This is the output of the write method
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqMDK.png]

I don't seem to understand how to get rid of the characters on the first line of the output and the t on each line

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` writes binary serialization data to the stream. It's not supposed to produce human-readable output.

If you want to write something human-readable, then use something like `PrintWriter` instead.